# Html div element content is out of the div

Tags: html, css

I have created an html file which can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/e86gvf5m/

The text "trigger event {event} {condition} {sourceDataPoint} "

```
<div id="triggerName">
    Trigger Event for ${recepientName}
    <br>
    ${event} ${condition} ${sourceDataPoint}
</div>
```

is supposed to be inside the black div. But it is kicked out of its containing div.

Please suggest how I can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: The black div is not `#triggerName`, it's `#recepientImage` (a sibling). I don't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues with your code, you have `float left;` needs to be `float: left;` and its styling the wrong div.

delete this from your css

```
#triggerName {
    float left;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

and add `float:left;` to

```
#recepientImage {
    background-color: #AFF; 
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left; <-- added
}
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15kvn5zL/1/)